# How to check if dictionary contains a key in bash?

Tags: bash, dictionary

I would like to check if a dictionary contains a key, but i dont know how.
I tried this:

```
if [ -z "${codeDict["$STR_ARRAY[2]"]+xxx}" ]
then
    echo "codeDict not contains ${STR_ARRAY[2]}"
    codeDict["${STR_ARRAY[2]}"]="${STR_ARRAY[3]}"
fi
```

Comment: You missed the `{}` on the `STR_ARRAY` expansion in the test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach (using `-z`), as this example shows:

```
$ declare -A a
$ a=( [a]=1 [b]=2 [d]=4 )
$ [[ -z ${a[a]} ]] && echo unset
$ [[ -z ${a[c]} ]] && echo unset
unset
```

However, there are a couple of issues with the code in your question. You're missing the curly braces around your inner array and personally I'd suggest that you use extended tests (`[[` instead of `[`) to avoid having to mess around with quotes:

```
$ str=( a b c )
$ [[ -z ${a[${str[0]}]} ]] && echo unset
$ [[ -z ${a[${str[2]}]} ]] && echo unset
unset
```

Comment: It doesn't distinguish between a missing entry and an entry whose value is an empty string.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `bash` 4.3, you can use the `-v` test:

```
if [[ -v codeDict["${STR_ARRAY[2]}"] ]]; then
    # codeDict has ${STR_ARRAY[2]} as a key
else
    # codeDict does not have ${STR_ARRAY[2]} as a key
fi
```

Otherwise, you need to take care to distinguish between keys that map to an empty string and keys that are not in the array at all.

```
key=${STR_ARRARY[2]}
tmp=codeDict["$key"]  # Save a lot of typing
# ${!tmp} expands to the actual value (which may be the empty string),
#         or the empty string if the key does not exist
# ${!tmp-foo} expands to the actual value (which may be the empty string),
#             or "foo" if the key does not exist
# ${!tmp:-foo} expands to the actual value if it is a non-empty string,
#              or "foo" if the key does not exist *or* the key maps
#              to the empty string.
if [[ ${!tmp} = ${!tmp-foo} || ${!tmp} = ${!tmp:-foo} ]]; then
    # $key is a key
else
    # $key is not a key
fi
```

In any version of `bash` that supports associative arrays, you can use a simple one liner if all you want to do is provide a default value for a key that does not exist.

```
: ${codeDict["${STR_ARRAY[2]}"]="${STR_ARRAY[3]}"}
```